# Regex working with calculator but not with AWS lambda function

Tags: regex, lambda

Trouble with regex and gather all data between [ and ].

Testing with the program: http://regexr.com/

String *data*

```
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "UserID": "1487840267893246",
      "Timestamp": 1487204364877,
    },
    {
      "UserID": "1487840267893336",
      "Timestamp": 1487204364888,
    }
  ],
  "Count": 2,
  "ScannedCount": 3
}
```

The below (fired in AWS lambda) has the intention of pulling all chars between the [ and ] and outputting it. (\[[^]*\]) works with the regex calc above, but only returns "undefined" in Lambda. Why?

```
Items = data.match(/"(\[[^]*\])"/);
console.log(Items);
```

Comment: Try `/"(\[[^\]]*\])"/` Some flavors interpret `[^]` to mean any character, other flavors trip on it. As a sidenote, if you ever want to do any character you can do something like `[\s\S]` which means `any whitespace character or any non-whitespace character`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative solution was to extract the data into an array as follows

```
userID = data.match(/"UserID":"([^"]+)"/g);
console.log(userID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the dotall flag:

```
Items = data.match(/"(?s)\[.*\]");
```

And you didn't need those brackets.